# Configuring Nginx to serve HTTPS is failing, however serving over HTTP is working

Tags: reactjs, nginx, web

First off, I completely understand there are many, many, articles out there that reflect this same topic. However, I having read and re-read many of them, I am still stuck.

I have a very simple static webpage (it's a `Hello World` HTML page, but eventually it will serve a production build react app), that I need to have served via *Nginx* over **HTTPS**.

I have been able to server the HTML over **HTTP**, but not **HTTPS**.

My *Nginx* config file that **works correctly** to serve over **HTTP** is:

```
server {
  listen 80; 

  server_name app.mycompany.com;
  root /opt/mycompany/mycompany-web/packages/client/build;
  index index.html;


  access_log /var/log/nginx/app.mycompany.com.access.log;
  error_log /var/log/nginx/app.mycompany.com.error.log debug;

  location / {
    try_files $uri /index.html =404;
  }
}
```

My *Nginx* config file that **does NOT work correctly** to serve over **HTTP** is:

```
server {
  listen [::]:443 ssl ipv6only=on;
  listen 443 ssl;

  server_name app.mycompany.com;
  root /opt/mycompany/mycompany-web/packages/client/build;
  index index.html;

  ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/app.mycompany.com/fullchain.pem;
  ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/app.mycompany.com/privkey.pem;
  include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf;
  ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem;

  access_log /var/log/nginx/app.mycompany.com.access.log;
  error_log /var/log/nginx/app.mycompany.com.error.log debug;

  location / {
    try_files $uri /index.html =404;
  }
}
```

Using the first config, my webpage is served correct, however, using the second config I simply get a 404.

From what I've read on the internet, the above looks correct.

*Does anyone see where I might be going wrong?* **How can I begin to debug my HTML not being served over HTTP?**

**Update (per Timo Stark's comment)**

`curl`ing to `https://localhost:443` returns a 404:

```
# curl -ikv https://localhost:443
* Rebuilt URL to: https://localhost:443/
* Hostname was NOT found in DNS cache
*   Trying 127.0.0.1...
* Connected to localhost (127.0.0.1) port 443 (#0)
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: none
  CApath: /etc/ssl/certs
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, Server hello (2):
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, CERT (11):
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, Server key exchange (12):
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, Server finished (14):
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, Client key exchange (16):
* SSLv3, TLS change cipher, Client hello (1):
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* SSLv3, TLS change cipher, Client hello (1):
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* SSL connection using ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384
* Server certificate:
*    subject: CN=app.mycompany.com
*    start date: 2020-03-31 18:34:56 GMT
*    expire date: 2020-06-29 18:34:56 GMT
*    issuer: C=US; O=Let's Encrypt; CN=Let's Encrypt Authority X3
*    SSL certificate verify ok.
> GET / HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.35.0
> Host: localhost
> Accept: */*
> 
< HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
* Server nginx/1.4.6 (Ubuntu) is not blacklisted
< Server: nginx/1.4.6 (Ubuntu)
Server: nginx/1.4.6 (Ubuntu)
< Date: Wed, 01 Apr 2020 00:02:16 GMT
Date: Wed, 01 Apr 2020 00:02:16 GMT
< Content-Type: text/html
Content-Type: text/html
< Content-Length: 177
Content-Length: 177
< Connection: keep-alive
Connection: keep-alive

< 
<html>
<head><title>404 Not Found</title></head>
<body bgcolor="white">
<center><h1>404 Not Found</h1></center>
<hr><center>nginx/1.4.6 (Ubuntu)</center>
</body>
</html>
* Connection #0 to host localhost left intact
```

**Update 2**

```
$ nginx -t
nginx: the configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf syntax is ok
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test is successful
```

And my */etc/nginx/nginx.conf* file is:

```
# cat /etc/nginx/nginx.conf

user  nginx;
worker_processes  1;
error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log warn;
pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;

events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}

http {
    include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

    sendfile        on;
    #tcp_nopush     on;

    keepalive_timeout  65;
    #gzip  on;
    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
}
```

Comment: can you share a curl statement? like `curl -ikv https://localhost:443`. Furthermore just for a better understanding: With the second configuration you are trying to server the site via httpS, don't you?

Comment: @TimoStark I updated the question with the `curl` response. And yes, with the second configuration I am trying to serve the site via HTTPS.

Comment: Can you share the output of `nginx -T`. Just want to see whats in the include. Beside from that: You should realy think abot updating your NGINX. We are runnig 1.17.6 currently. More critical. You should not use `SSLv3` any longer. Is there any special need staying with the old version and SSL Version?

Comment: @TimoStark I added the output of `nginx -t` to the post. I also upgraded Nginx. However, I'm not sure how to modify the SSLv3. So I'm looking into that.

Comment: You can join your `server` blocks using only one block with two (or three) different `listen` directives, both 80 and 443 ports.